# Why does django cart template_tags bring the error message object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: django

```
register = template.Library()
@register.filter

def cart_item_count(user):
    if user.is_authenticated:
        qs = Order.objects.filter(user=user, ordered=False)
        if qs.exists():
            return qs[0].item.count()
    return 0
```

Comment: How do you use this filter?

Comment: This is *not* a question. You should explain *what* you aim to do, what you tried, and what is not working. See [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank for giving me a hint on how to ask question. I was using the filter to display the total number counts of items in the cart

Answer (score 0):

The template uses as parameter the `user`, you will thus need to work with a `User` object that you filter, for example the logged in user with:

```
{{ user|cart_item_count }}
```

In your template filter you can improve the efficiency by working with:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def cart_item_count(user):
    return Item.objects.filter(order__user_id=user.pk, order__ordered=False).count()
```

It might however make more sense to work with a [*custom template tag* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags).